# Ubuntu - Booting black screen with purple border

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub2

After the installation of Ubuntu, when I try to boot a black screen with a purple box appears without let me see the GRUB menu. Then the screen becomes black and Ubuntu starts booting. Ubuntu is the only OS installed, but it's quite annoying as I can't see the bootloader options. What could be wrong?

Comment: Could you clarify whether Ubuntu boots finally or the boot fails?

Comment: It is also worth noting that after you exit this menu you also have to run the command sudo update-grub

Comment: @tia_0, if you've found an answer helpful, accept it by selecting the grey checkbox below the up- and down-vote toggles.

Answer (score 1):

When Ubuntu is the only installed OS, the GRUB menu is automatically hidden as per default. To change this, edit your GRUB configuration using the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then you have to replace the following line:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT= ...
```

with this one:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
```

To learn more about the options in /etc/default/grub, run the following command to browse the GRUB info page:

```
info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'
```

Comment: @LewisMcGinley adds that "It is also worth noting that after you exit this menu you also have to run the command `sudo update-grub`"